# switching list elements with dataframe rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Consider my list `IDs` that has a dataframe of behaviours in each one:

```
IDs <- list(Dave = data.frame(Behaviour  = c("Aggression","Interaction", "Nursing"), number  = c(20,10,5), duration = c(60,39,27)),James = data.frame(Behaviour  = c("Aggression","Interaction"), number  = c(21,30), duration = c(30,49))) 

IDs 


    $Dave
    Behaviour number duration
1  Aggression     20       60
2 Interaction     10       39
3     Nursing      5       27

$James
    Behaviour number duration
1  Aggression     21       30
2 Interaction     30       49
```

**Note that James does not exhibit any nursing behaviour and therefore different number of rows between the two list elements.**

I want to switch the list elements with the dataframe rows so that I have a list of behaviours and a dataframe of ID. So that it looks like this:

```
   $Aggression
     ID number duration
1  Dave     20       60
2 James     21       30

$Interaction
     ID number duration
1  Dave     10       39
2 James     30       49

$Nursing
    ID number duration
1 Dave      5       27
```

I thought that it could be achieved with `reshape2::melt`. I wasn't able to get further than `melt(IDs, id = "Behaviour)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you can do it in two steps:

1. turning the list into a single data.frame/data.table
2. splitting it based on Behavior

You can do it like this, for example:

```
dt <- data.table::rbindlist(IDs, id = "ID")
# or: dt <- dplyr::bind_rows(IDs, .id = "ID")

split(dt, dt$Behaviour)
```

Note:

If you don't want the Behaviour column in the result and you used the data.table approach, you can modify the split to:

```
split(dt[,!"Behaviour"], dt$Behaviour)
```

Comment: This simple answer is definitely what I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tmp<-data.frame(ID=rep(names(IDs),vapply(IDs,nrow,1L)),do.call(rbind,IDs),row.names=NULL)
split(tmp[-2],tmp$Behaviour)
#$Aggression
#     ID number duration
#1  Dave     20       60
#4 James     21       30
#$Interaction
#     ID number duration
#2  Dave     10       39
#5 James     30       49
#$Nursing
#     ID number duration
#3  Dave      5       27
#6 James      1       17
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `base R`

```
d1 <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, id = names(IDs), IDs))
split(d1, d1$Behaviour)
```

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I didn't find it when I was posting it.